# ios publish / rollout options for different versions / customizations of the same application to different customers?

Tags: ios, app-store, publish, rollout, app-distribution

Current issue: How do we efficiently deploy different versions of the same App to different customers?

Example:

App version 1.1 needs to be installed for customer A.

App version 1.2 needs to be installed for customer B.

App version 1.3 needs to be installed for customer C.

App versions 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 are basically the same application with small differences between them (probably different backend versions required). Some features might be missing or might be extra on some versions depending on customers explicitly wanting them or not, or the branding might be different: different logo, different theme etc. It is basically the same codebase but with variations specifically asked by the clients.

We need a way to publish the app and indicate to our customers which app version they need to install. What options do we have?

I would really appreciate an answer from someone who dealt with this kind of situation before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Apple support, not a question about programming as defined by the [help].

Comment: But i did not raise this question under programming - as far as I know stackoverflow is not programming only questions.
Anyway here is the answer from apple support:
"We are unable to provide pre-approval or guidance on app ideas or concepts. After you have submitted your app, we will provide feedback during the review process, if applicable.
If we have questions about your app or any of its implementations during review, we will reach out to you directly." - do you understand know why I am looking for answers from someone who already dealt with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to give application with slightly changes by features to different users. Firstly you can only submit 1 final build on the App Store. There is no such option for uploading separate versions on the store while keeping the old version.

But if you have fixed set of users than you should have some of the options like :

1. First option is you can upload 3 different distribution builds on TestFlight & invite the users on the specific build where you wants them to access the features
2. Another option is you can create the links on the online link services from where you can generate the links for the app & you can distribute that links to the specific users
3. Last option is you can create a single build only but you can control the features hide & show on basis of APIs & by that way you can give the access of specific features to the relevant users only

I hope this will help everyone.

Comment: The problem is that it`s basically not the same application. The application is branded differently for each customer (theme, logo, even name) - only the codebase is the same. The above answer does not apply to this scenario